# Android LoadAnimation error

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, viewflipper

I want to create an animation in Android for a ViewFlipper. I made the xml files and I know try to create the animation but the eclipse gives me an error.

> The method loadAnimation(Context, int) in the type AnimationUtils is
>   not applicable for the arguments (LoafMakingTutorial, View)

and this is the code

```
Animation right_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoafMakingTutorial.this,findViewById(R.anim.right_flip_in));
```

What is the problem? I've already tried the solutions that the eclipse mentioned, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Message shows you exactly what you need to know:

The method loadAnimation(Context, **int**) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments (LoafMakingTutorial, **View**)

You can't use a *View* as a parameter for a method that expects an int. 
Just change the `findViewById` part. If you already have the *ID* of the `View` you don't have to look for the `View`behind that *ID*.

Comment: I've edited the question to post the problematic line of codes.

Comment: I am not sure if this is 100% working, but you should be able to leave out the call to `findViewById`, because `R.anim.right_flip_in`is already an int.